# Open and read a file from outside of project VS2013

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I can't read for write a file from outside of project. There is no link option when I add existing item, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to add the file as a reference to your project, or that you want to modify the data in the file with your code?

If you want to add the file and reference it within your project, you should be able to do so by right clicking on the project name, then

`Properties->Common Properties->References->Add New Reference->Browse`

Then locate the file you want to reference.

As for reading from and writing to a file, you can `#include <fstream>` and use `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` for input and output, respectively.

You could do it like so:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void main() {
    string file = "C:\\Users\\Foo\\Desktop\\Bar.txt";

    ofstream output(file);
    output << "Hello World" << endl;
    output.close();

    ifstream input(file);
    string inputStr;
    while(input >> inputStr) {
        cout << inputStr << endl;
    }

    return;
}
```